# Startup job/task not working on windows

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I've registered a new startup job as follows

```
$trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtStartup -RandomDelay 00:00:30

$option =  New-ScheduledJobOption -RunElevated –ContinueIfGoingOnBattery

Register-ScheduledJob -Name startup_test -FilePath C:\startup.ps1 -Trigger $trigger -ScheduledJobOption $option
```

My startup.ps1 script is as follows

```
New-Item c:\test_startup_success.txt -type file
```

When I restart the windows server 2012 R2 core, it doesn't create the file. Have restarted using

```
shutdown /r
```

But if I use test it using, it created the file

```
Start-Job -DefinitionName startup_test
```

Is there anything that I'm missing which needs to be done specifically for startup jobs?

Update:

I executed the following command to see if the job failed, but the output was empty.

```
Get-WinEvent -LogName Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler/Operational | Where {$_.Message -like "*fail*"}
```

My wild guess is that the job itself is not getting executed. Some condition is probably not getting satisfied. Even the Job trigger is enabled

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0> Get-ScheduledJob | Get-JobTrigger
Id         Frequency       Time                   DaysOfWeek              Enabled
--         ---------       ----                   ----------              -------
1          AtStartup                                                      True
```

Comment: When you test it are you running from an elevated shell?

Comment: Yes.. I ran it in Elevated shell.

Comment: I've also added the same in options for ScheduledJob

Comment: try changing the random delay from 2 minute to 30 seconds. It is a good idea to specify a random delay period of 30 seconds to one a minute to help to avoid race conditions at startup. This will also help ensure a greater chance of success for the job.

Comment: Potentially a permissions issue? Windows Vista and later are a bit picky about saving stuff to Root C and require elevated access, while you are telling it to run elevated you have not provided credentials to use so perhaps it is failing there. You could test by writing to a more publicly accessible file.

Comment: By default it will use credentials of current user if not specified (per the help).  See `Get-Help about_Scheduled_Jobs_Troubleshooting` and go through that carefully first.

Comment: @DewiJones Tried that as well. Didn't work.

Comment: @Deadly-Bagel  I tried with switching the directory to C:\test\test_startup_success.txt.

Comment: Read a similar blog from Microsoft Scripting Guy and he does the exact same thing however he doesn't specify any $option, just the task with the trigger, I'll see if I can find it once I'm at work

Comment: As promised :) https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2014/05/14/use-powershell-to-create-job-that-runs-at-startup/

Comment: @DewiJones I started with the same blog actually. But it didn't work so looked out for more and got one blog asking to add RunElevated as option.

Comment: Hmm, it really does sound like a permissions issue, have you tried creating a folder and giving permission to everyone (Temporarily of course!) and seeing if it runs then?

Comment: @DewiJones Yes I did. I think the job itself is not getting triggered. In case of failure I would get some error logs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107001/discussion-between-dewi-jones-and-nilesh).